# Application level static variable value does not retain new value assigned in Activity Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, global-variables

Inside 'MyApplication' Class extending class 'Application'

```
 public static int globalflag = 0;
```

In the debugger the value of 'globalflag' at the launch of the MainActivity is 0. I go to the Fragment 'MyFragment' and change the value there:

```
 MyApplication.globalflag = 1;
```

The value updates in the debugger too. Now when I press the back button the value of MyApplication.globalflag in the debugger shows as 0 (no longer retains the value).

How can I make sure this value is retained for the entire Application life cycle?

I am a beginner in Android development and appreciate any input for this problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the why I think that is happening:

Your `Application` instance lifecycle is tied to the components that constitute your app.

As the wise [Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLifeCycle/article.html#application) says.

> The application object is created whenever one of your Android
>   components are started. It is started in a new process with a unique
>   ID under a unique user. Even if you do not specify one in your
>   AndroidManifest.xml file, the Android system creates a default object
>   for you.

Moreover:

> The application object starts before any component and **runs at least
>   as long as** another component of the application runs.

So this means that when you press the back button on your `Activity` triggering the end of life cycle of the Activity (effectively killing it)
the Application instance might also be garbage collected/killed by the system for its resources (because effectively it is not needed).

There are other better mechanisms to preserve state between activity / application lifecycle such as `SharedPreferences` or SQLite

You can check [this tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) for more detail on how to use `SharedPreferences`

But it's simple:

```
Context context = getActivity();
SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(
        getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Writing / saving data:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), newHighScore);
editor.commit();
```

Reading persisted data:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int defaultValue = getResources().getInteger(R.string.saved_high_score_default);
long highScore = sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), defaultValue);
```